# SQL Server Compact Edition requirements (*.sdf file)

Tags: sql-server-ce

**The story (if needed for the answer):**

I have a strange problem and don't know how to describe it correctly. I've coded a program in C# with a win7 64bit machine. I tested it with a 32bit win7 netbook with Visual Studio and even with a 32bit win7 without Visual Studio (that's the strange part) and it worked. But when I brought it to the person I made it for it didn't work on win7 32bit with .NET Framework 4.5 and the newest Windows updates installed on 2 different PC's.

Back at home I did some further testing under an XP machine and I went into the same trouble. I decided to install C# to debug but after it was installed the program worked even without debugging! Even after uninstalling C# again.

I went back to the PC's that were still not working and installed the SQL Server Compact Edition runtime but that didn't do the trick. The exception always says something about `System.Io.FileNotFound` but as I said after installing VS it works. I can't and don't want to install my students version of C# there so...

The question:
Can anyone please tell me what additional software needs to be installed to run an app against a `*.sdf` file used by SQL Server Compact Edition that get's installed with Visual Studio?

**UPDATE - SOLVED:**
Solved it today! :-)
32bit OS: Uninstall all CE installations then install SSCERuntime_x86-DEU.msi if you have Win7 32bit.
64bit OS: Install BOTH SSCERuntime_x86-DEU.msi and SSCERuntime_x64-DEU.msi if you have a 64bit win7 version.

What helped was a try-catch over all and the Exception parameter .ToString() in catch block displayed in a MessageBox. Told me the exact KB-whatever to google it.